# Array object in array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an array of objects and that objects also have an array of objects. I'm getting it with an ajax request and want to make a select with that JSON data. Cant solve this problem) i've tried a lot of examples.

```
Object service_problems: 
   Array[3]
     0: Object
       id: 2
       name: "bla bla"
        problems: Array[2]
          0: Object
            id: 3,
            name: 'blab bla'

          1: Object
             id: 4,
             name: 'bla blae'
```

From this data i want to make a select with optgroup and options:

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="service_problems.name">
        <option value="3">blab bla</option>
        <option value="4">bla blae</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Also my PHP code:

```
if ($request->ajax()) {
            $services = DeviceType::find($request->type_id);
            $services = $services->services;

            $service_with_problems = [];

            function findServiceProblems($id) {
                $service = Service::find($id);
                return $service->serviceProblems;
            }

            foreach ($services as $service) {
                $service_problems = findServiceProblems($service->id);

                array_push($service_with_problems, [
                    'id' => $service->id,
                    'name' => $service->name,
                    'service_problems' => $service_problems
                ]);
            }

            return response()->json(['service_problems' => $service_with_problems]);
        }
```

help pls)

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem)

```
jQuery.map(data['service_problems'], function (problem) {

    options += '<optgroup label="'+ problem.name +'">';

    jQuery.map(problem.problems, function (data) {
        options += '<option>'+ data.name +'</option>';
    });

    options += '</optgroup>';
});
```